# How to assign the output results at the loop for in maxima to different variables

Tags: loops, for-loop, save, output, maxima

I want to save the output of this **for** to different variables, for example, matrix **A1**, **A2** and **A3**.

```
B:matrix([0,-%pi/2,theta[1],0],[0,%pi/2,0,d[2]],[a[3],0,theta[3],0]);

D:matrix_size(B);

for i: 1 step 1 thru D[1] do
display(A:matrix([cos(B[i,3]),(-sin(B[i,3])*cos(B[i,2])), sin(B[i,3])*sin(B[i,2]), 
    B[i,1]*cos(B[i,3])],[sin(B[i,3]),cos(B[i,3])*cos(B[i,2]),-
    cos(B[i,3])*sin(B[i,2]),B[i,1]*sin(B[i,3])],[0,sin(B[i,2]),cos(B[i,2]),B[i,4]],[0,0,0,1]));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use subscripted variables.

```
for i:1 thru 3 do A[i] : <complicated stuff>;
```

Constructing variables A1, A2, A3 ... is possible but considered bad form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [operator ::](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_7.html#IDX263)

```
B:matrix([0,-%pi/2,theta[1],0],[0,%pi/2,0,d[2]],[a[3],0,theta[3],0]);

D:matrix_size(B);

for i: 1 step 1 thru D[1] do
concat('A, i) :: matrix([cos(B[i,3]),(-sin(B[i,3])*cos(B[i,2])), sin(B[i,3])*sin(B[i,2]), 
  B[i,1]*cos(B[i,3])],[sin(B[i,3]),cos(B[i,3])*cos(B[i,2]),-
  cos(B[i,3])*sin(B[i,2]),B[i,1]*sin(B[i,3])],[0,sin(B[i,2]),cos(B[i,2]),B[i,4]],[0,0,0,1]);
```